# Byrd vs. Byrd: What's in a name?

Tags: style, names

Fans of jazz who have come across the works of [Charlie Byrd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charlie_Byrd) and [Donald Byrd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_Byrd) might have wondered if ever there was ever a blood relation between the two.

The only link apparent in discography was Donald's [Byrds Word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byrd%27s_Word) and three years on, Charlie's [Byrds Word!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byrd%27s_Word!). Yet it seems they never played together in the same session as never did Charlie's brother [Joe Gene Byrd](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joe_Gene_Byrd) (not to be confused with the more avant garde [Joseph Byrd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Byrd)).
Neither are we sure on the lineage of Eric Byrd from the well known [Eric Byrd trio](https://ericbyrdtrio.com/trio/). There was a distinct difference in styles too, Charlie was a guitarist and arranger with a Latin bent, Donald was ubiquitous in his many ensemble and band appearances as a saxophonist.

There is a long list of other musical Byrds such as [Professor Longhair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Byrds#Formation_(1964)), [Bobby Byrd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Yardbirds), [Jerry Byrd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerry_Byrd), [Jonathan Byrd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jonathan_Byrd_(musician)), [Steve Byrd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steve_Byrd), [Winston Byrd](https://www.allaboutjazz.com/tag-winston-byrd), and even [Toni Byrd](https://www.gigsalad.com/toni_byrd_atlanta). Again, all from completely disparate styles of music.

Fans/Googlers may also be familiar with the band, [The Byrds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerry_Byrd) whose name does not relate to anything related to jazz at all, (if that were ever the case, could have [The Yardbirds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jonathan_Byrd_(musician)) from the year before been part inspiration?)

Even though the [name of Byrd](https://forebears.io/surnames/byrd) is rare in some parts of the world compared to the U.S, (from where most of the above-mentioned Byrds emanate), can we ever assume the name applies more to musicians than not?

Comment: You've overlooked [William Byrd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Byrd).